# If Else Statement Not working inside .each()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When submit the form it runs both means to say code inside if is running and after else code is also running.

```
$("#new_chq").submit(function(){

    var inputs = document.getElementsByName("val_2[]");
    var i;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= inputs.length; i++) {

       $('#file_'+i).each(function() {
        
          if(!$('#file_'+i).val() == ''){
    
             $('#text_'+i).attr('required', '');
             return false;        
          }
          else{
             return true ;
          }
       });
    }        
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @ Felix Kling  stop code running when if condition true.

Comment: While inside the jQuery's `each`... your `return false;` means this: Break the loop! So, before the loop place a variable, say `var valid=true`, than inside the loop if necessary change to `valid=false;` - later on, after the loop you can return true or false to stop submitting the form...

Comment: @ skobaljic already did as you say but not working

Comment: Which could should stop running? As mentioned, the return statements are inside the `.each` callbacks so they won't affect anything outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
> callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
> continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
> iteration.

So, you need to move the form event handling after the jQuery each-loop.

Here is an example:

```
$("#new_chq").on('submit', function() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('[id^=file_]').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasAttr('required') && !$(this).val()) {
            isValid = false;
            return false; // <- this breaks the loop
        };
    });
    return isValid;
});
```

Please note, there are other errors in your code, such as `$('#file_'+i).each` loop, which has no sense - that is one element with unique id.